# How to distinguish interface extension

Tags: java, interface

I'm reading the book Introduction to Java Programming. About interface and abstract class, there is a graph: [image]

> Class1 implements Interface1 ; Interface1 extends Interface1_1
>   and Interface1_2 . Class2 extends Class1 and implements Interface2_1 and
>   Interface2_2 .

As shown above, **it doesn't say Interface2_1 extends interface1 explicitly**. But in  the graph it shows the relationship indeed. Is it just an error or this extension relationship can be derived?

**EDIT**==================================================================

In the book, the condition is:

> Class1 implements Interface1 ; Interface1 extends Interface1_1
>   and Interface1_2 . Class2 extends Class1 and implements Interface2_1 and
>   Interface2_2.

But it gives the graph above. The condition doesn't show Interface2_1 extends Interface1. But the graph shows that. I mean that is the graph wrong? Or the extension relationship can be inferred accoring to the condition?

Comment: Are you facing any issue to understand the concept of `interface` and `inheritence`? Any specific question related to OOPS concept? `Class1` also extends `Object` class but that is not maintained any where it is by implicit in Java. Every class extends `Object` class by default.

Comment: Yeah. I want to know if classA implements interface1.  classB is the subclass of classA. classB implements interface2. Is it correct to say interface2 must be the subinterface of interface1? Because the graph shows that. I don't know whether it's an error of that book.

Comment: Most likely it was left this out. You could suggest a correction to the author.

Comment: Do you mean "class1" and "class2" rather than "classA" and "classB"? Otherwise, I'm not sure which classes you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a newer in Java. And maybe I'm wrong, instead of the author.

Comment: yes `Interface2_1` extends `Interface1` that indirectly extends `Interface1_1` and `Interface1_2`. Not true for `Interface2_2`

Comment: But the condition is : **Class1 implements Interface1 ; Interface1 extends Interface1_1 and Interface1_2 . Class2 extends Class1 and implements Interface2_1 and Interface2_2** .   It doesn't say Interface2_1 extends Interface1. Can this be derived?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "derived". It's indicated by the line between the boxes in the diagram.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry for that. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the textual description

> Class1 implements Interface1 ;
>
> Interface1 extends Interface1_1 and Interface1_2 .
>
> Class2 extends Class1 and implements Interface2_1 and Interface2_2.

The line between `Interface2_1` and `Interface1` should not be there. And it is not even implicitly there as you can implement `Class3 implements Interface2_1` which has absolutely nothing to do with all the other interfaces mentioned.

`Class2` implements `Interface1`, `Interface1_1`, and `Interface1_2` because it extends `Class1`.